# snakemake: multiple --wrapper-prefix values?

Tags: snakemake

I'm constructing a pipeline that accesses both wrappers within snakemake's official wrapper repository and custom wrappers hosted in my own GitHub repository. It would be much more convenient to assume a specific prefix when different phrases are used (e.g., `"main/wrapper/dir"` would point to my GitHub, while any other shorthand would point to the wrapper repo.)

I've stumbled upon `--wrapper-prefix` and see that it points to the official wrapper repo by default. As expected, changing this to point to my repo means that I can no longer access the snakemake repo.

Is there a known way to specify multiple `--wrapper-prefix` values when running snakemake -- where if a wrapper isn't in one repo, it looks in the other one?

Or if this isn't possible, is there a way to access different wrapper prefixes based on different leading words? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you ask for, but you could make your personal wrappers a python package (See my own snakemake wrappers package here: https://gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/snakemake_wrappers/-/blob/master/README.md).

The installation of the wrappers can be made via the `package_data` argument of `setup`:

https://gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/snakemake_wrappers/-/blob/master/setup.py

And the path to your installed wrappers can be exported in the `__init__` file, as I do here:

https://gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/snakemake_wrappers/-/blob/master/smwrappers/__init__.py

Then, for instance, in my Snakefile, I can import and use this directory:

```python
from smwrappers import wrappers_dir
# [...]
rule map_on_genome:
    # ...
    wrapper:
        f"file://{wrappers_dir}/map_on_genome"
```